# UK Visa Overstayed what next?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, overstaying

I overstayed on a UK Visa (a couple of years) for personal reasons, then I've decided to leave voluntary, without telling them I'm leaving , I bought the ticket and left in 2018, I did check in, none of them told me anything, no immigration control, no passport check, no stamp nothing at all, 
My question is :

Will they know I have overstayed? In the future will this bring me a problem to enter the UK?

How to check if I'm allowed or not to enter in the future?

Comment: What is your citizenship? When did you overstay?

Comment: Non-EU country , I left uk last year

Comment: @Traveller The traveler likely knows his citizenship whatever it is doesn’t affect the ban

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate because of the additional question

Comment: Then the duplicate parts should be edited out.

Answer (score 3):

They know you overstayed and you have a one year ban starting from your departure date.

Yes it will affect your future reentry even after your ban is over. **You will likely not get a UK visa for a very long time, maybe ever**. Two years is a long time and immigration cannot trust you. They don’t care about your personal reasons.

You do not need to check with anyone, [the rules are explicit](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf)

### Voluntary departure at person’s own expense

Unless they are applying for entry clearance as a family member (under Appendix FM of the Immigration Rules), or they were under 18 at the time of their most recent breach (as set out at paragraphs A320 and 320(7B) of the Immigration Rules), the following categories of offender will ordinarily be **subject to a mandatory one year re-entry ban** if they leave the UK voluntarily at their own expense:

- illegal entrants
- those who breach a condition attached to their leave
- those who overstay their lawful leave by more than:

  o  90 days, excluding any exceptional periods, where the overstaying began up to and including the 5 April 2017

  o 30 days, excluding any exceptional periods, where the overstaying began on or after 6 April 2017

### TL:DR

If you married or somehow become a UK citizen or EU National, the overstay rules change

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just to make this clear to myself, If I apply for a family visa or spouse visa, or student visa, it will be hard to get this type of visas in the future , even I have returned vulentary and survived by myslef and some friends help , without any state benefit whatsoever , no crime , even i did not use public hospital . Thank you for your help

Comment: @Melfc According to https://www.drummondmiller.co.uk/news/2014/05/immigration-overstaying-know-the-meaning-and-its-implications/ the act of overstaying in itself is a criminal offence

Comment: @Melfc I believe family member and spouse visa is excluded. They won’t hold the overstay against you. You don’t seem to want to accept that regardless of whether you left yourself or didn’t use public services, you’re a lawbreaker. You overstayed for two whole years. You should not expect leniency.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and your help .